# mysql Insert Text problem

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert

I'm having a nightmare trying to insert some data in to a table. For some reason it will only let me insert numbers and not text in to a specific row, not even a single word. I've tried setting the row to different types (Text, Varchar, Longtext), but no joy is there any reason for this? I've done this loads of times before and I'm completely stuck as to why it's now not working.

The problem rows are order_note and test, here's the query:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "dpsc_transactions";
$query = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} (`invoice`, `date`, `order_time`, `billing_first_name`, `billing_last_name`, `billing_country`,
`billing_address`, `billing_city`, `billing_state`, `billing_zipcode`, `billing_email`, `phone`, `shipping_first_name`, `shipping_last_name`,
`shipping_country`, `shipping_address`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_state`, `shipping_zipcode`, `products`, `payment_option`, `discount`,
`tax`, `shipping`, `total`, `order_note`, `test`, `payment_status`) VALUES ('{$invoice}', NOW(), {$order_time}, '{$bfname}', '{$blname}', '{$bcountry}', '{$baddress}',
'{$bcity}', '{$bstate}', '{$bzip}', '{$bemail}', '{$phone}', '{$sfname}', '{$slname}', '{$scountry}', '{$saddress}', '{$scity}', '{$sstate}', '{$szip}',
'{$products}', '{$payment_option}', {$dpsc_discount_value}, {$tax}, {$dpsc_shipping_value}, {$dpsc_total}, {$order_note}, {$test}, 'Pending')";
$wpdb->query($query);
```

Comment: What's the mysql error, you are seeing?

Comment: Is the  `row_id = woodoo`? paste the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}dpsc_transactions (`invoice`, `date`, `order_time`, `billing_first_name`, `billing_last_name`, `billing_country`,
`billing_address`, `billing_city`, `billing_state`, `billing_zipcode`, `billing_email`, `phone`, `shipping_first_name`, `shipping_last_name`,
`shipping_country`, `shipping_address`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_state`, `shipping_zipcode`, `products`, `payment_option`, `discount`,
`tax`, `shipping`, `total`, `order_note`, `test`, `payment_status`) VALUES ('{$invoice}', NOW(), '{$order_time}', '{$bfname}', '{$blname}', '{$bcountry}', '{$baddress}',
'{$bcity}', '{$bstate}', '{$bzip}', '{$bemail}', '{$phone}', '{$sfname}', '{$slname}', '{$scountry}', '{$saddress}', '{$scity}', '{$sstate}', '{$szip}',
'{$products}', '{$payment_option}', '{$dpsc_discount_value}', '{$tax}', '{$dpsc_shipping_value}', '{$dpsc_total}', '{$order_note}', '{$test}', 'Pending')";
$wpdb->query($query);
```

Or tell what says mysql error.

Comment: Explaining what you changed is usually a good idea :) Sure I found it, but it took a minute.

Comment: The changes are to put quotes around the `test` and `order_note` variables in the VALUES() section.

Comment: **Yep that was it, I needed to add quote marks around the variable**, it must be that if your inserting numbers you don't need the quote marks, and if you're inserting text you do. And as I copied the code from a numbers variable I missed the quote marks!! The simplest things waste a crazy amount of time. **Many thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

You're not trying to insert data that's too long are you?

Comment: OP says, "not even a single word"